# Error converting data type varchar to numeric in select statement

Tags: sql

Table structure:

```
(code VARCHAR(5),
description VARCHAR(150),
tax_rate DECIMAL(5,2),)


SELECT t1.code AS code, t1.code AS value, t1.code AS description,
       t1.code + (' + tax_rate + '%)' AS content
 FROM pbostaxinfo t1
```

The 'tax_rate' prompt the error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I want the result to show  eg: AJP (6%).

AJP is the code, and 6 is tax_rate.

Comment: Which DBMS? What is the error? What does the data in the field look like?

Comment: make sure you used the single quote properly

Comment: `+` is invalid for varchars in SQL to concatenate strings in SQL you need to use `||`

Comment: `t1.code + '(' + tax_rate.toString() + '%)' AS content`

Comment: `value` is a reserved word in ANSI SQL, needs to be delimited as `"value"`.

Comment: t1.code + (' + tax_rate + '%)' AS content
justy looks wrong.
The % cannot be part of a decimal.
Are you trying some kind of dynamic SQL operation here.  It's not clear.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t1.code AS code, t1.code AS value, t1.code AS description, t1.code + ' (' + CAST(t1.tax_rate AS VARCHAR(5)) + '%)' AS content
FROM pbostaxinfo t1
```

This is the answer for what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT t1.code AS code,
  t1.code      AS value,
  t1.code      AS description,
  t1.code
  ||'('
  ||tax_rate
  ||'%)' AS content
  FROM pbostaxinfo t1
```